# How to display a image from a table in a div when i mouse hover to the table row?

Tags: jquery, html, json

Consider I have table with two rows. Each rows contains some user image. ( Actually I have populated table data from JSON using ajax call). So , When i mouse hover to the particular row, it should display that particular rows image in a div. How to achieve this using jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to show that image in the div. I have solved it in the fiddle.
Here is the [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YLsWZ/)

**HTML CODE**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.mentoringminds.com/images/LinkedInIcon.png" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/view-256.png" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="displayDiv">
    <img src="" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$("td img").mouseover(function(){
    $("#displayDiv img").attr("src",$(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Hop, it may help you. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: FYI, I have stored user images in JSON file.

Comment: Please upvote & mark the answer as correct if it halped you. Thanks :)